# Load function calling simultaneously android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a same function (**loadItems()**) for different objects creation. All classes extends the abstract class named **Item** which has the implementation for **loadItems()**.

```
carMan = new CarMan();
carMan.loadItems();

truckMan = new TruckMan();
truckMan.loadItems();

bikeMan = new BikeMan();
bikeMan.loadItems();

cycleMan = new cycleMan();
cycleMan.loadItems();
```

I should not wait for "truckMan.loadItems()" get called after finishing the "carMan.loadItems()".

loadItems will load the item for each objects.

I know, I can use AsyncTask inside the loadItems().

But one problem is there, I have to send the success event after all objects loadItems() successfully done their jobs.

I am in confused state. Could any one please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at ReactiveX (and RxJava2) it's meant to handle these kind of process handling the threading too. You shouldn't use AsyncTask due to potential memory leaks and other side effects.